# Jquerry, отловить количество символов

Tags: jquery

Коллеги, как вывести сообщение alert как только наберётся 3 символа ? 
Я так понимаю keyup функция. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Больше вводных. Какие символы? Где они находятся? Считается ли пробел за символ?

Comment: Буквы, кириллица. Пробел не считается.

Comment: Воспользуйте кнопкой "править", чтобы дополнить ваш вопрос. И неплохо бы добавить вашу разметку

Answer (score 0):

```js
const $input = $('.input');

$input.on('keyup keypress', () => {
  const letters = $input.val().match(/[^\s]/gi);
  if(letters !== null && letters.length >= 3) alert(`Вы ввели: ${letters.length} символов.`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
```